# Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome Conky does not work right

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, gtk3, conky

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu gnome 16.04 and I installed icon and theme and much. Finally I installed `conky-manager` but it doesn't work correct like this.

[image]

Comment: Same here, I gave up trying to adjust every thing, the images and text would just not align for me at all. I did remove the title bars though. Go to the folder of your conky theme and open its config file (manager will tell you the location), find the line `own_window_type default` and change it to `own_window_type desktop` and the title will be gone. It is a start at least. I thought it was just me with this issue, as I could not find any information, but I guess not.

Comment: Do you have the correct font installed? Check the font name in the conky file. From looking at the [original output](http://seajey.deviantart.com/art/Conky-Seamod-v0-1-283461046), your font isn't correct to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conky changed the `conkyrc` format to lua in the recent versions, the original seamod (and 99% of all other conkys out there) still have the old format.

Thankfully, user maxiwell on [Github](https://github.com/maxiwell/conky-seamod) has already converted the popular seamod theme for Ubuntu 16.04. Since askubuntu/Stackoverflow prefers source instead of links, here the `conkyrc.lua`:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                               conkyrc_seamod
-- Date    : 04/23/2016
-- Author  : SeaJey and Maxiwell
-- Conky   : >= 1.10 
-- License : Distributed under the terms of GNU GPL version 2 or later
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

conky.config = {

    background = true,
    update_interval = 1,

    cpu_avg_samples = 2,
    net_avg_samples = 2,
    temperature_unit = 'celsius',

    double_buffer = true,
    no_buffers = true,
    text_buffer_size = 2048,

    gap_x = 80,
    gap_y = 70,
    minimum_width = 300, minimum_height = 900,
    maximum_width = 350,
    own_window = true,
    own_window_type = 'override',
    own_window_transparent = true,
    own_window_argb_visual = true,

    own_window_type = 'override',
    own_window_class = 'conky-semi',
    own_window_hints = 'undecorated,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below',
    border_inner_margin = 0,
    border_outer_margin = 0,
    alignment = 'top_right',


    draw_shades = false,
    draw_outline = false,
    draw_borders = false,
    draw_graph_borders = false,

    override_utf8_locale = true,
    use_xft = true,
    font = 'caviar dreams:size=11',
    xftalpha = 0.5,
    uppercase = false,

-- Defining colors
    default_color = '#FFFFFF',
-- Shades of Gray
    color1 = '#DDDDDD',
    color2 = '#AAAAAA',
    color3 = '#888888',
-- Orange
    color4 = '#EF5A29',
-- Green
    color5 = '#77B753',
-- Loading lua script for drawning rings
    lua_load = '~/.conky/seamod/seamod_rings.lua',
    lua_draw_hook_pre = 'main',

};

--${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color1}${pre_exec lsb_release -d | cut -f 2} - $sysname $kernel
conky.text = [[
${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=bold}${color4}SYSTEM ${hr 2}
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color1}$sysname $kernel
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color1}Battery:  ${color3}${battery_bar 5,150 BAT0} ${color3}${battery_percent BAT0}%
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color1}Uptime: ${color3}$uptime

# Showing CPU Graph
${voffset 20}
${offset 125}${cpugraph cpu0 40,220 666666 666666 -0.5 -l}${voffset -25}
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=bold}${color5}CPU
# Showing TOP 5 CPU-consumers
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color4}${top name 1}${alignr}${top cpu 1}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color1}${top name 2}${alignr}${top cpu 2}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color2}${top name 3}${alignr}${top cpu 3}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color3}${top name 4}${alignr}${top cpu 4}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color3}${top name 5}${alignr}${top cpu 5}%

#Showing memory part with TOP 5
${voffset 40}
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=bold}${color5}MEM
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color4}${top_mem name 1}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 1}
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color1}${top_mem name 2}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 2}
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color2}${top_mem name 3}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 3}
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color3}${top_mem name 4}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 4}
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color3}${top_mem name 4}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 5}

# Showing disk partitions: root, home and files
${voffset 12}
${offset 180}${color1}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}Disk Read: ${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${color2}${diskio_read}
${offset 180}${color1}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}Disk Write: ${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${color2}${diskio_write}
${voffset -30}
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=bold}${color5}DISKS
${offset 120}${diskiograph 33,220 666666 666666}${voffset -30}
${voffset 20}
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Free: $color3${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${fs_free /}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Used: $color3${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${fs_used /}
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Free: $color3${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${fs_free /home}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Used: $color3${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${fs_used /home}
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Free: $color3${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${fs_free /media/files}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Used: $color3${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${fs_used /media/files}

# Network data (my desktop have only LAN). ETHERNET ring is mostly useless but looks pretty, main info is in the graphs
${voffset 40}
${offset 200}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Lan IP: ${alignr}$color3${addr wlan0} 
${offset 200}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Ext IP: ${alignr}$color3${execi 3600 wget -q -O /dev/stdout http://checkip.dyndns.org/ | cut -d : -f 2- | cut -d \< -f -1} 
${voffset -30}
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=bold}${color5}ETHERNET
${voffset 40}             
${offset 15}${color1}${font ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}Up: ${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}$color2${upspeed wlan0} / ${totalup wlan0}
${offset 15}${upspeedgraph wlan0 40,320 4B1B0C FF5C2B 1280KiB -l}
${offset 15}${color1}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}Down: ${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}$color2${downspeed wlan0} / ${totaldown wlan0}
${offset 15}${downspeedgraph wlan0 40,320 324D23 77B753 1280KiB -l}

${color4}${hr 2}




]];
```

and the `seamod_rings.lua`:

```
--==============================================================================
--                            seamod_rings.lua
--
--  Date    : 05/02/2012
--  Author  : SeaJey
--  Version : v0.1
--  License : Distributed under the terms of GNU GPL version 2 or later
--
--  This version is a modification of lunatico_rings.lua wich is modification of conky_orange.lua 
--
--  conky_orange.lua:    http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=137503&forumpage=0
--  lunatico_rings.lua:  http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=142884
--==============================================================================

require 'cairo'

gauge = {
{
    name='cpu',                    arg='cpu1',                  max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=150,
    graph_radius=54,
    graph_thickness=5,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=0,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=9.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='cpu',                    arg='cpu2',                  max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=150,
    graph_radius=48,
    graph_thickness=5,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=0,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=9.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='cpu',                    arg='cpu3',                  max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=150,
    graph_radius=42,
    graph_thickness=5,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=0,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=9.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='cpu',                    arg='cpu4',                  max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=150,
    graph_radius=36,
    graph_thickness=5,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=0,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=9.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='cpu',                    arg='cpu5',                  max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=150,
    graph_radius=30,
    graph_thickness=5,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=0,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=9.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='cpu',                    arg='cpu6',                  max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=150,
    graph_radius=24,
    graph_thickness=5,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=0,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=9.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='cpu',                    arg='cpu7',                  max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=150,
    graph_radius=18,
    graph_thickness=5,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=0,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=9.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='cpu',                    arg='cpu8',                  max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=150,
    graph_radius=12,
    graph_thickness=5,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=0,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=9.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='memperc',                arg='',                      max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=325,
    graph_radius=54,
    graph_thickness=10,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=42,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=23,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=2,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.5,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=10.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='fs_used_perc',           arg='/media/files',                     max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=490,
    graph_radius=54,
    graph_thickness=7,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=64,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=23,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=2,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='Files',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=12.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.5,
},
{
    name='fs_used_perc',           arg='/home/',                     max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=490,
    graph_radius=42,
    graph_thickness=7,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=32,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=23,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=2,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='Home',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=12.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.5,
},
{
    name='fs_used_perc',           arg='/',                     max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=490,
    graph_radius=30,
    graph_thickness=7,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=22,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=23,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=2,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='Root',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=12.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.5,
},
{
    name='downspeedf',           arg='wlan0',                     max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=690,
    graph_radius=54,
    graph_thickness=7,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=0,
    txt_radius=64,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='Down',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=12.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.5,
},
{
    name='upspeedf',           arg='wlan0',                     max_value=100,
    x=65,                          y=690,
    graph_radius=42,
    graph_thickness=7,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=0,
    txt_radius=30,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='Up',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=12.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.5,
},
}

-- converts color in hexa to decimal
function rgb_to_r_g_b(colour, alpha)
    return ((colour / 0x10000) % 0x100) / 255., ((colour / 0x100) % 0x100) / 255., (colour % 0x100) / 255., alpha
end

-- convert degree to rad and rotate (0 degree is top/north)
function angle_to_position(start_angle, current_angle)
    local pos = current_angle + start_angle
    return ( ( pos * (2 * math.pi / 360) ) - (math.pi / 2) )
end


-- displays gauges
function draw_gauge_ring(display, data, value)
    local max_value = data['max_value']
    local x, y = data['x'], data['y']
    local graph_radius = data['graph_radius']
    local graph_thickness, graph_unit_thickness = data['graph_thickness'], data['graph_unit_thickness']
    local graph_start_angle = data['graph_start_angle']
    local graph_unit_angle = data['graph_unit_angle']
    local graph_bg_colour, graph_bg_alpha = data['graph_bg_colour'], data['graph_bg_alpha']
    local graph_fg_colour, graph_fg_alpha = data['graph_fg_colour'], data['graph_fg_alpha']
    local hand_fg_colour, hand_fg_alpha = data['hand_fg_colour'], data['hand_fg_alpha']
    local graph_end_angle = (max_value * graph_unit_angle) % 360

    -- background ring
    cairo_arc(display, x, y, graph_radius, angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, 0), angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, graph_end_angle))
    cairo_set_source_rgba(display, rgb_to_r_g_b(graph_bg_colour, graph_bg_alpha))
    cairo_set_line_width(display, graph_thickness)
    cairo_stroke(display)

    -- arc of value
    local val = value % (max_value + 1)
    local start_arc = 0
    local stop_arc = 0
    local i = 1
    while i <= val do
        start_arc = (graph_unit_angle * i) - graph_unit_thickness
        stop_arc = (graph_unit_angle * i)
        cairo_arc(display, x, y, graph_radius, angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, start_arc), angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, stop_arc))
        cairo_set_source_rgba(display, rgb_to_r_g_b(graph_fg_colour, graph_fg_alpha))
        cairo_stroke(display)
        i = i + 1
    end
    local angle = start_arc

    -- hand
    start_arc = (graph_unit_angle * val) - (graph_unit_thickness * 2)
    stop_arc = (graph_unit_angle * val)
    cairo_arc(display, x, y, graph_radius, angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, start_arc), angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, stop_arc))
    cairo_set_source_rgba(display, rgb_to_r_g_b(hand_fg_colour, hand_fg_alpha))
    cairo_stroke(display)

    -- graduations marks
    local graduation_radius = data['graduation_radius']
    local graduation_thickness, graduation_mark_thickness = data['graduation_thickness'], data['graduation_mark_thickness']
    local graduation_unit_angle = data['graduation_unit_angle']
    local graduation_fg_colour, graduation_fg_alpha = data['graduation_fg_colour'], data['graduation_fg_alpha']
    if graduation_radius > 0 and graduation_thickness > 0 and graduation_unit_angle > 0 then
        local nb_graduation = graph_end_angle / graduation_unit_angle
        local i = 0
        while i < nb_graduation do
            cairo_set_line_width(display, graduation_thickness)
            start_arc = (graduation_unit_angle * i) - (graduation_mark_thickness / 2)
            stop_arc = (graduation_unit_angle * i) + (graduation_mark_thickness / 2)
            cairo_arc(display, x, y, graduation_radius, angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, start_arc), angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, stop_arc))
            cairo_set_source_rgba(display,rgb_to_r_g_b(graduation_fg_colour,graduation_fg_alpha))
            cairo_stroke(display)
            cairo_set_line_width(display, graph_thickness)
            i = i + 1
        end
    end

    -- text
    local txt_radius = data['txt_radius']
    local txt_weight, txt_size = data['txt_weight'], data['txt_size']
    local txt_fg_colour, txt_fg_alpha = data['txt_fg_colour'], data['txt_fg_alpha']
    local movex = txt_radius * math.cos(angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, angle))
    local movey = txt_radius * math.sin(angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, angle))
    cairo_select_font_face (display, "ubuntu", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, txt_weight)
    cairo_set_font_size (display, txt_size)
    cairo_set_source_rgba (display, rgb_to_r_g_b(txt_fg_colour, txt_fg_alpha))
    if txt_radius > 0 then
        cairo_move_to (display, x + movex - (txt_size / 2), y + movey + 3)
        cairo_show_text (display, value)
        cairo_stroke (display)
    end

    -- caption
    local caption = data['caption']
    local caption_weight, caption_size = data['caption_weight'], data['caption_size']
    local caption_fg_colour, caption_fg_alpha = data['caption_fg_colour'], data['caption_fg_alpha']
    local tox = graph_radius * (math.cos((graph_start_angle * 2 * math.pi / 360)-(math.pi/2)))
    local toy = graph_radius * (math.sin((graph_start_angle * 2 * math.pi / 360)-(math.pi/2)))
    cairo_select_font_face (display, "ubuntu", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, caption_weight);
    cairo_set_font_size (display, caption_size)
    cairo_set_source_rgba (display, rgb_to_r_g_b(caption_fg_colour, caption_fg_alpha))
    cairo_move_to (display, x + tox + 5, y + toy + 5)
    -- bad hack but not enough time !
    if graph_start_angle < 105 then
        cairo_move_to (display, x + tox - 30, y + toy + 1)
    end
    cairo_show_text (display, caption)
    cairo_stroke (display)
end


-- loads data and displays gauges
function go_gauge_rings(display)
    local function load_gauge_rings(display, data)
        local str, value = '', 0
        str = string.format('${%s %s}',data['name'], data['arg'])
        str = conky_parse(str)
        value = tonumber(str)
        draw_gauge_ring(display, data, value)
    end

    for i in pairs(gauge) do
        load_gauge_rings(display, gauge[i])
    end
end

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                                         MAIN
function conky_main()
    if conky_window == nil then 
        return
    end

    local cs = cairo_xlib_surface_create(conky_window.display, conky_window.drawable, conky_window.visual, conky_window.width, conky_window.height)
    local display = cairo_create(cs)

    local updates = conky_parse('${updates}')
    update_num = tonumber(updates)

    if update_num > 5 then
        go_gauge_rings(display)
    end

    cairo_surface_destroy(cs)
    cairo_destroy(display)

end
```

This should give you the original seamod appearance back[image: Seamod on 16.04].

All credit goes to user maxiwell from Github.

Comment: It did not work, exactly the same problem. I tried every thing I could think of. I think it is a Gnome issue, seems to work for others on Unity.

Comment: Yeah, Unity with no issues here, can confirm. This seems to be a Gnome quirk for whatever reason, I cannot replicate it with Unity.

Comment: I am going to give you a vote up anyway because it was a good try, if you get one more vote in the next 24 hours, I will let the system auto award you the half bounty because it was a good effort and something I did not find but I am thinking there is no solution right now, all I can think is the conky team did not update it for Gnome 3.18 :(

Answer (score 3):

### Use an updated seamod and try set window type to dock or normal

On Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, [maxiwell's update of seamod](https://github.com/maxiwell/conky-seamod) worked for me (as mentioned by emk2203's answer), **but provided** I edited the `conkyrc.lua` to use the 'dock' or 'normal' window type and use window manager hints. E.g the following are key config values to use:

```
own_window_type = 'dock',
own_window_hints = 'undecorated,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below',
```

`own_window_type = 'normal'` with the above `own_window_hints` also worked okay.

**Beware**, maxiwell's `conkyrc.lua` has a typo where `own_window_type` is set twice. Remove the duplication if you use it.

What didn't work:

- `own_window_type = 'desktop'` doesn't work well as conky disappears when clicking desktop items.
- `own_window_type = 'override'` causes `X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)` in Ubuntu Gnome and also doesn't support background transparency.

And of course, it needs the `conky-all` package, not `conky-std`, as seamod depends on cairo to draw the gauges/rings.

### My own working example

I reworked and forked maxiwell's update [here](https://github.com/JPvRiel/conky-seamod). It has a readme with instructions on how to install and autostart conky (should hopefully work with most Gnome 3.18+ desktop environments with conky 1.10+). My version also has fixes to include a border and semi-transparent background.

Comment: Setting the window type to "panel" also works, and is nicer as the desktop recognizes it as a side/top bar, so dragging windows to the side won't go over it.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be of much help...I'm using a different Desktop Environment. But I had some similar issues today. My rings and font were all messed up.

My rings, it turns out, were just in the wrong directory. But I submitted an answer here in another thread. It may warrant investigation, or set you on the right path again. Good luck!

[Conky does not use instructed font with "can't load Xft font" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788228/conky-does-not-use-instructed-font-with-cant-load-xft-font-error/805467#805467)