# Conky does not use instructed font with "can't load Xft font" error

Tags: fonts, conky

`conky: can't load Xft font 'Ubuntu:size=8,weight:normal'` is the error message which appears in the terminal.

`use_xft yes` is present in the Conky config file.

The Conky file can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/0BN2kYff)

Answer (score 3):

I poked around on this, and with *my* environment, I had some different issues.

I'm using Unity with Compiz. My Lua Rings weren't working, and neither were my fonts. My Lua Rings were just in the wrong directory.

I had changed the font to Ubuntu. However, the format was wrong as indicated in this thread. However, my format didn't match any of the ones listed here in previous comments.

I'm attaching a sample of some of my properly formatted text from the memory section of my Seamod that works with my environment:

```
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:bold:size=10}${color5}MEM
```

So for me, I had to find and replace:

```
font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal
```

with

```
font Ubuntu:bold:size=10
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

`Ubuntu:size=8,weight:normal`

try

`font = 'Ubuntu:normal:size=8'`

This assumes you are using Conky version 1.10.

Answer (score 2):

Conky 1.10 configuration file use a new syntax ! 
Usually, it can convert old file "on the fly" but it seems that the version of 16.04 have some issue.

I had the same problem as you since I updated my machine. After a lot research, it seems that you must convert your configuration file to the new format.

To help you, there is a script located in :

```
/usr/share/doc/conky-all/convert.lua
```

see here : [Convert to new 1.10 syntax](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Convert-to-new-1.10-syntax)

You must install "lua5.2" first and then make the script executable (as root)

Then, from ~/.conky where your config file should be located :

```
/usr/share/doc/conky-all/convert.lua <your_conkyrc>
```

Pay attention :

- the configuration file should be in the "old" format
- the conversion script overwrite the old version ! Make a copy before if needed

Then, you will still have the problem with the font, but if you convert as explained by DK Bose, it should work (it worked for me)

```
{font Ubuntu:bold:size=7}
```

(no '=' after 'font')

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Just remove "`,weight`" part from font lines in `conky` config:

For example, replace

```
[...]
${color5}${font Ubuntu:size=8,weight:normal}TOP
${font Ubuntu:size=8,weight:normal}${color1}${top name 1}${alignr}${top cpu 1}%
[...]
```

by

```
[...]
${color5}${font Ubuntu:size=8:normal}TOP
${font Ubuntu:size=8:normal}${color1}${top name 1}${alignr}${top cpu 1}%
[...]
```

P.S. Tested on Lubuntu 16.04 (conky 1.10).

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04!

Comment: I did it in Linux Mint 19 (Tara) Mate and after reload conky, same error appear. Like my config haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

That might be https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/issues/778 - use "true" instead of "yes".